# jsf commandButton using tags in value

Tags: jsf, icons, commandbutton

Not sure if possible, but I'm using bootstrap for most of my school project. One design attribute I usually use in my admin panels are the use of icons (edit = pencil, remove = cross, add = plus, ...).

So to render those simple buttons i use the following code:

```
<a href="#" class="btn"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a>
```

In use with JSF I tried using:

```
<h:commandButton value="<i class='icon-delete icon-white'></i>" class="btn-danger" action="#{horseController.delete(item.id)}" />
```

But it seems the '<' is not permitted as stated in this error message:

> Error Parsing /admin/horses.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 27] The value of
>   attribute "value" associated with an element type "null" must not
>   contain the '<' character.

So my question is: How is it possible to be using tags, in this case for the use of icons, in a commandButton?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `<h:commandButton>` is the wrong tag for the purpose. It generates a HTML `<input type="submit">` element while you need a HTML `<a>` element. You need a `<h:commandLink>` instead.

```
<h:commandLink class="btn-danger" action="#{horseController.delete(item.id)}">
    <i class="icon-delete icon-white" />
</h:commandLink>
```

Comment: thanks, thought the commandLink would have done the same... Havent tested it though. Shame on me! :)